# Is unmanaged Visual C++ running on CLR?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, clr

If I write a C++ code in Visual C++ without using any managed code is it still running on CLR? If it is, How can I write a native app using Visual C++. Is there any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Unmanaged" code does not use the CLR; it is native code.

Answer (score 1):

Common Language Runtime (CLR) is what executes .NET framework programs. This includes managed C++ that is completely different than native C++.

If you are using MS Visual Studio, you can create application written using native C++ using MFC, Win32 or ATL project templates.